# pdo can't allow reuse of placeholders - what's an alternative for searching multiple columns?

Tags: php, pdo

My code is like this:

```
Select * from tableX where tableX.column1 LIKE %:testString%' OR 
tableX.column2 Like '%:testString% OR ... '
```

Now obviously this won't work, because testString is a named placeholder that is being repeated. I can't do testString2, testString3 etc, because I'll be looking up 20-30 columns! It'll be a pain!

Any easier workaround?

Comment: Either generate names dynamically or use `?`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario can you mix ? with bindParam? I would like to use bindParam for other part of the query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to include the % signs in the parameters, not in the query

> $testString =%testString%

Also using unnamed parameters ,? , requires a separate parameter for each ?. Using named parameters avoids this.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("Select * from tableX where tableX.column1 LIKE :testString
                      OR tableX.column2 Like :testString OR ... ");
$stmt->bindParam(':testString',$testString, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```